# Neo4j Matching Variable number of relationships from previous query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The code on the [Neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) shows the following for matching against a variable number of relationships.

```
MATCH (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen' })-[:ACTED_IN*1..3]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN movie.title
```

I am trying to do this based on a previous query using a `WITH` statement but cannot find the right syntax. Everything I try yields an error. I am aiming for something of the form:

```
MATCH p = ...
...
WITH length(p) AS len_p
MATCH (charlie { name: 'Charlie Sheen' })-[:ACTED_IN*len_p..len_p]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN movie.title
```

However, this syntax yields `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError`.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

You can use the [apoc.path.expandConfig](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-querying/expand-paths-config/) procedure to perform variable-length relationship queries with dynamic bounds.

For example (to get paths of length `len_p` consisting of `ACTED_IN` relationships ending in a `Movie` node):

```
...
WITH length(p) AS len_p
MATCH (charlie:Person {name: 'Charlie Sheen'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(charlie, {
    relationshipFilter: 'ACTED_IN',
    labelFilter: '>Movie',
    minLevel: len_p,
    maxLevel: len_p
}) YIELD path
RETURN LAST(NODES(path)).title AS title
```

Comment: Trying to implement this, how would this filter for the end of the path, `(movie: Movie)`

Comment: I have edited the answer to add an appropriate [labelFilter](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-querying/expand-paths-config/#path-expander-paths-config-config-label-filters).